# The W3C's tabular-data-model is de facto in use?

Tags: csv

In nowadays (2016) what standard is a [*de facto* standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard) for [CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) file metadata, 
   [*W3C's tabular-data-model*](http://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-model/) or [*OKFN's tabular-data-package*](http://dataprotocols.org/tabular-data-package/)?

---

### NOTES

Important to remember: these metadata standards (W3C or OKFN) are [machine-readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_data).  The question is not about human-readable standard, like a README format.

PS: [original question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598173/w3cs-tabular-data-model-de-facto-in-use), checking if here is correct/better place.

Comment: I hesitate to put this as a full answer, but I think that neither qualifies as a de facto standard. I am not sure I've ever seen either actually in use as part of a published data set, and I'm a somewhat active user of open data.